# Degree of splitting field of $X^n-1$ over $F_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Suppose that $n$ is a natural number and p is a prime that does not divide n. Let $L$ be the splitting field of the polynomial $X^n-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Show that $[L:\mathbb{F}_p]$ is the smallest natural number k s.t. $p^k=1$ mod n.

Solution:
We know that $\#L=p^k$ for some k and $L$ is absolutely determined by that. We also know that the multiplication group $L^*$ is cyclic $p^k-1$ group. So $L$ has n solution to the equation $x^n=1$ iff n divides $p^k-1$. Thus $p^k=1$ mod n.

First I have not been able to prove the step that $x^n=1$ iff n divides $p^k-1$. I thought of looking at it as integers with respect to sum module $p^k-1$. Then the equation is of the form $nx=0$ and then we want to show that this has n solutions iff n divides $p^k-1$.

Secondly, in this solution I find no attempt to show that k is the smallest number but I guess that is the property of the splitting field, if it were not the smallest number then it would be a splitting field for other irreducible polynomial over $\mathbf{F}_p$

Comment: The solution relies on the following basic fact about cyclic groups. $C_r$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $C_s$ if and only if $s\mid r$. Here the roots of $X^n-1$ form a cyclic group of order $n$, and the solution uses the fact that such a group exists inside $L^*$ if and only if $n\mid p^k-1$. You only the smallest positive $k$, because the splitting field is the smallest field containing such a group. Your idea of looking at solutions of the congruence $nx\equiv 0\pmod{p^k-1}$ is ok, and leads to the same conclusion. But it is simpler to think in terms of that general result.